# Classifier JSONObject does not have a 'companion object, and thus must be initialized here

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, companion-object

```
import org.json.JSONObject
JSONObject deviceInformation = ...
```

[image]

I tried to create a companion object like this, but not really working... sorry pretty noobie in Java and Kotlin....
[image]

and yes, JSONObject is imported correctly with

`import org.json.JSONObject`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using incorrect syntax. Variables in Kotlin are declared like:

```
[var/val] name: OptionalExplicitType = something
```

Which means `JSONObject var instance:...` isn't allowed.

Change that to:

```
var instance: JSONObject = ...
```

It's also important that you set it. Since it looks like you're trying to create a singleton, you can just use an `object` instead of a class.

If you feel like doing it the old fashioned way, make it nullable:

```
var instance: JSONObject? = null
```

Then check if it's null, initialize, set and return of it is, otherwise return the current value.

If this isn't your goal though, you still need to initialize it, unless you make it lateinit. But if you do that, you need to initialize it before attempting to access it, or it will throw an exception.

Comment: yes and in additional, I actually imported a WRONG JSONObject class, which actually need to be `import net.sf.json.JSONObject`. Which is crazy strange, but it was required by the object that I instantiated. before this piece of JSONObject related code...